# Lodash throttle firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, throttling

I am using lodash throttle like this

```
const throttledFetch = _.throttle(fetch, 10000, { 'leading': false });
```

I need to trigger this upon a certain notification event I am getting from a ws. So the idea was, if I get 10 notifications at almost the same time, to have the `fetch` function fire only once at the wait of 10 seconds.

Instead, what is happening is that the fetch functions gets fired 10 times after the 10 second delay.

How can I fix this? I could use any other methods.

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: what does the `fetch` function look like?

Comment: () => {dispatch(someAction())}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter for the invocation and check it for invoking only once.

Comment: Yes, I could. I am waiting to see if there is some way why the throttle is not working, else I will go with your answer.

Comment: I'll mark it as resolved, since I went for this route. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The throttled function should remain the same between re-renderings, meaning we have to use React's UseCallback function. This would have worked if you changed:

```
const throttledFetch = _.throttle(fetch, 10000, { 'leading': false });
```

To

```
const throttledFetch = useCallback(_.throttle(fetch, 10000, { 'leading': false }), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

if we are going to call the `fetch` function only once, for all the N requests at same time, we should be using `debounce` instead of `throttle`. That is the best way to respond to user interaction / some event from the Web socket listener.

The response should be faster, and also it should not be called frequently. In order to full fill the above requirement, I would be going with `_debounce`.

As answered by `Tuxedo Joe` in the above answer, we can go with `useCallback` approach, since the reference is going to stay the same between re-renders.

`const asyncFetch = useCallback(_.debounce(fetch, 10000, { 'leading': false }));`